# How do I put a p tag under two divs?

Tags: html, css

So I've two divs positioned next to each other via float left for the left div and float right for the right div. I want my p to appear underneath these two divs. However it just refuses to do that. It always appears at the top of the page or between the two divs. I've already tried setting the two divs to display inline block but then they don't stay next to each other and do a line-break instead. I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS so maybe its just a simple beginners fault but I would be gratefull if someone could help me out.

```css
.p {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.tippsboxright {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  max-width: 45%;
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxleft {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="boxleft">
      <img src="../images/questionguy.png" alt="Typ mit fragen" class="imgkauftipps">
    </div>
    <div class="tippsboxright">
      <p>
        This is the right box with text inside of it.
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="p">This is the p tag that I want to be at the bottom of the page.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use CSS flexbox for this instead of float. Put the top divs in a wrapper/container and give the wrapper `display: flex`. That's basically it, but you can finesse it as I've done in this example:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrap div {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Me non paenitet nullum festiviorem excogitasse ad hoc. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse. Quam temere in vitiis, legem sancimus haerentia. Inmensae subtilitatis, obscuris et malesuada fames. Fictum, deserunt mollit anim laborum astutumque!</p>
```

Or, using the html from your example, except I've moved the `<p>` tag out of the wrapper. Does the `<p>` *have* to be in the wrapper div?

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="boxleft">
      <img src="../images/questionguy.png" alt="Typ mit fragen" class="imgkauftipps">
    </div>
    <div class="tippsboxright">
      <p>
        This is the right box with text inside of it.
      </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <p class="p">This is the p tag that I want to be at the bottom of the page.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get this type of layout, and while floating is the oldest and most common, it's not really designed for this type of thing. `float` is designed for text to flow around the block, like you see in magazines. So that's what you see happening: your text is flowing around the floats. There is a way to stop this though: `clear`. Clear tells text to not flow around `left`, `right`, or `both` floated objects. So you can use that to get the layout you desire:

```css
.p {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.tippsboxright {
  background: lightyellow;
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  max-width: 45%;
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxleft {
  background: lightblue;
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="boxleft">
      <img src="../images/questionguy.png" alt="Typ mit fragen" class="imgkauftipps">
    </div>
    <div class="tippsboxright">
      <p>
        This is the right box with text inside of it.
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="p">This is the p tag that I want to be at the bottom of the page.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

It is however better and easier to use either flex box or grid layouts in this case. They are designed for block style layouts, which seems to be what you want, not flowing text around blocks.